# Connections to SQL Server broken after Windows updates

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have Visual Studio 2013 C# solution that worked fine until some automatic Windows updates were pushed out to my PC. After these updates I am get an error on the `connection.open` command (server does not exist or access denied error message).

I created a new solution only for connection test purposes and from the newly created solution the connection to the same server is successful.

I uninstalled the Windows updates and my connections still don't work.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I verified the .net framework versions in the 2 projects and they are the same 4.5.1. I don't understand the different functionality for the same code in the 2 solutions.

Comment: What if you overwrite the broken connection string with the working connection string? Just to make sure there isn't another issue going on (odd invisible character perhaps).

Comment: Where is your connection string that is failing?

Comment: I overwrote the string in my existing solution with the one that worked from the new solution and it did not work.

Comment: Check any security software you might have to see if it is blocking the non-functioning app

Comment: here is the connection string that works in the new solution and does not work in the existing solution:            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("user id=mroberts;password=;server=echoloaderdbp;Trusted_Connection=yes; database=Echo_SBU_Custom; connection timeout=5");
                conn.Open();
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("sp_CHG", conn) ;
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataReader sdr = comm.ExecuteReader();

Comment: Remember - same connection string in the 2 different solutions : one created before the windows updates one newly created after the windows updates

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the appropriate information.

Comment: Not sure if its the issue, but your connection string specifies Trusted_Connection=YES, which enables Windows Authentication - but also specifies a SQL username and password. I believe those settings contradict each other.

Answer (score 0):

open run type `services.msc` press enter
it will show you list of services then go down and find `SQL Server(MSQLSERVER)`
and right click on it and press **start**.
hope this helps you

Comment: If the service is down then how do you explain that the test connection works?

Comment: the service is not down -

Comment: _I created a new solution only for connection test purposes and from the newly created solution the connection to the same server is successful._

Comment: I did - same outcome

Comment: https://www.sqlserverlogexplorer.com/database-does-not-exist-access-denied/

Comment: check that link it may help you

Comment: Steve - the new solution I created has only one Form and one Button on the form - on the button click event all i have is a connection to the same SQL server - and it is a successful connection -